# Validating presence with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

This is my first time testing in rails and I'm having trouble with what I think should be a pretty simple validation.

In group_spec.rb

```
it { should validate_presence_of(:enc_key) }
it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:enc_key).case_insensitive }
```

In my model

```
validates :enc_key, :presence => true, uniqueness: {:case_sensitive => false}
```

When I run rspec I'm getting

```
 2) Group should require enc_key to be set
    Failure/Error: it { should validate_presence_of(:enc_key) }
      Expected errors to include "can't be blank" when enc_key is set to nil, got errors: ["owner There is no owner associated with this group. (nil)", "name can't be blank (nil)", "name is
too short (minimum is 4 characters) (nil)", "stripped_name can't be blank (nil)"]
```

The list of errors are generated from other validations and I've tried writing a custom validation but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using shoulda matchers here and I can't see anything wrong with your test.

I think you should be using the `validates` method rather than the `validate` method in you model. `validates` is used to declare the kind of validation rules that you are specifying here. `validate` is used to declare custom validations.

So try this in your model:

```
validates :enc_key, presence: true, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
```

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates

and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validate

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my part. I am using validates and the test is still failing. As for shoulda matchers - I would assume so. Someone else actually wrote the test cases .

Answer (score 0):

The shoulda matchers are designed to work with otherwise valid records. They change various aspects of the record and test that the validation reports the appropriate error. If there are already errors in the record, this approach generally doesn't work.

You haven't shown the rest of your spec, but I gather than `subject` is nil. You need to set `subject` to be a valid instance of your record.

See https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/365 for a related discussion of this.